# Linux system with no internet connection, dealing with system date

Tags: linux, date, ntp

We're developing a vending machine that will run a Xubuntu 18.04 in a Single Board Computer with a browser in kiosk mode, the machine won't be able to connect to the internet on most of the cases. However, as the machine needs to perform scheduled tasks, we need the operator to be able to set the machine date and time.

I have been searching and found that there are actually two date/time sources in Linux, one is set by the hardware clock and the other by Linux itself (date command). There are also tools to synchronize both of them depending on what we consider to be "correct".

So, in a machine with no Internet connection and hence with no NTP access, is it advisable to let the machine operator change the system date and then synchronize the hardware clock with it? We consider our application will not be affected by this change, but I don't know what the effect could be in the system.

Comment: No, the machine has only the Xubuntu OS. The issue here isn't about the difference between hwclock and date, but, after days, months, years, .. without internet access the machine being set the good date.

Comment: I haven't used it, but I think `adjtimex` is what you are looking for: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/man8/adjtimex.8.html